# Ordenar listas de la A la Z

Tags: c#, lista

Tengo un par de listas donde tengo datos de archivos que subo mediante un `input`

```
List<List<string>> filasArchivo2 = new List<List<string>>();
```

Esta lista esta compuesta por varias posiciones, lo cuales esas posiciones significan filas en un archivo de excel.

La primera posición o fila, son los encabezados de un archivo de excel, la segunda es el valor de la columna y así sucesivamente.

He intentado con el método `Sort()` pero agarra todo y no quiero que también agarre los encabezados. también con el `Skip()` pero tampoco me da.

```
//filasArchivo2.Sort();

var filaOrdenada = filasArchivo2;

filaOrdenada.Skip(1).OrderBy(x => x[1]);
```

En esta foto estoy en la posición 1, lo cual es la segunda fila. Y lo que necesito es ordenar a partir de la posición 1 y dentro del mismo, tomar la posición 0 y ordenarlo de la A la Z.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: el codigo nos va a ayudar mas que la imagen.. y un ejemplo que podamos copiar, tambien...

Comment: Luis, pon un ejemplo del resultado que deseas obtener

Comment: Que quieres decir con x=>x[1], eso funciona?

Comment: quiere decir que los ordena a partir de la posición 1, osea de la segunda posición

Comment: Eso está mal Luis, pon un ejemplo real, da detalles explícate bien que ya tú llevas tiempo en la comunidad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use un bucle for para recorrer los elementos de cada lista interna a partir del segundo elemento, y luego compara los elementos correspondientes de `a` y `b` utilizando la función `CompareTo`. Si encuentra dos elementos diferentes, devuelve el resultado de la comparación, que se utiliza para ordenar la lista. Si todos los elementos son iguales, devuelve 0.

```
filasArchivo2.Sort((a, b) =>
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < a.Count; i++)
                    {
                        int cmp = a[i].CompareTo(b[i]);
                        if(cmp != 0)                                
                        {
                            return cmp;
                        }
                    }
                    return 0;
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

`filaOrdenada.Skip(1).OrderBy(x => x[1]);` Este código NO ordena la lista `filaOrdenada`, lo que hace es crear una NUEVA lista ordenada. Por lo que tu necesitas guardar el retorno de dicha función, de esta manera

```
var filaOrdenada = filasArchivo2.Skip(1).OrderBy(x => x[1]);
```

Suponiendo que `x => x[1]` está bien, la función de arriba retornará una lista ordenada exceptuando la cabecera, para incluirla, debería hacer algo así:

```
var filaOrdenada = filasArchivo2.Take(1).Union(filasArchivo2.Skip(1).OrderBy(x => x[1]));
```

Comment: pero no puedo juntar una `List` con una `IEnumerable<List>`

Comment: @Luis ¿Ni empleando el método `IEnumerable<List>.ToList()`? que convierte la enumeración en lista.

Comment: @Luis No entiendo... `Take` y `OrderBy` retornan un `IEnumerable`, porque no los vas a poder juntar?

Comment: No, sí... mala mía, perdón. Estaba pensando otra cosa.

Comment: @Luis Entonces? Te funcionó?

Comment: En parte sí pero no,  la primera ya no me devuelve como la tenía pero no alfabéticamente, lo hace como `CFQ7TTC0HL8Z:0001-P1Y-Monthly` y debería de ser como `CFQ7TTC0HBSJ:0001-P1Y-Monthly`

Comment: Por qué en excel cuando los ordeno manualmente, me los muestra así.